# I cant delete a google drive archive (pd: sorry for my bad english)

Tags: google-account, google-drive

Ok so long time ago my google drive account was like ban so of course i cant use it but for some reason when i enter the google drive mobile app its appears some wierd photos i tried to delete but obviouly my account was banned so it pop up a message saying unable to open the menu of the archive

If there another way to delete this fotos

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try to delete photos from "Album Archive" (if that's the issue)

1. In Auto-backup select the folder holding a picture or pictures
2. Click the 3 dot option: Manage in Google Photos
3. select the photos followed by the 3 dot option to Move to trash
4. When empty refresh the page by hitting F5 on Windows or the refresh circular arrow to the left of the URL
5. Wait until the page is fully reloaded

   If the deleted photos reappear, you can go to https://photos.google.com/ and click on the 3 bar menu: Help and feedback: Send feedback, and copy/paste the following sentence:-

I provide consent for you to look into my account in order investigate  issue #b_120099634
followed by the folder name causing problems and any other information you determine is important.

Comment: Its doenst work, the photos reapper in google drive

Comment: Is there like a way to unbann my google drive account?

Comment: I think your google drive acc can't be banned separately from an entire google act, if that makes sense. You can request access to it again and try to restore your account. Sign in to your Google Account on a browser, then choose "Try to restore and just follow the instructions. And also they have a specific form that you have to fill out if you have issues with your request. https://support.google.com/accounts/contact/disabled2